# Unable to update Craft: 'requires yiisoft/yii2-queue 2.1.0'

Tags: updating

I've got another update issue with the following error. Can anyone help?

```
    craftcms/cms 3.0.27 requires yiisoft/yii2-queue 2.1.0 -> 
    satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-queue[2.1.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

composer.json looks like this

```
{
"name": "craftcms/craft",
"description": "Craft CMS",
"keywords": [
"craft",
"cms",
"craftcms",
"project"
],
"license": "MIT",
"homepage": "https://craftcms.com/",
"type": "project",
"support": {
"email": "support@craftcms.com",
"issues": "https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues",
"forum": "https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/",
"source": "https://github.com/craftcms/cms",
"docs": "https://craftcms.com/docs",
"rss": "https://craftcms.com/changelog.rss"
},
"require": {
"craftcms/cms": "3.0.23.1",
"vlucas/phpdotenv": "v2.4.0",
"craftcms/ckeditor": "1.0.0-beta.2",
"craftcms/redactor": "2.1.6",
"cebe/markdown": "1.1.2",
"composer/ca-bundle": "1.1.1",
"composer/composer": "1.6.3",
"composer/semver": "1.4.2",
"composer/spdx-licenses": "1.3.0",
"craftcms/oauth2-craftid": "1.0.0.1",
"craftcms/plugin-installer": "1.5.2",
"craftcms/server-check": "1.1.1",
"creocoder/yii2-nested-sets": "0.9.0",
"danielstjules/stringy": "3.1.0",
"doctrine/lexer": "v1.0.1",
"egulias/email-validator": "2.1.4",
"elvanto/litemoji": "1.3.1",
"ezyang/htmlpurifier": "v4.10.0",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "6.3.3",
"guzzlehttp/promises": "v1.3.1",
"guzzlehttp/psr7": "1.4.2",
"justinrainbow/json-schema": "5.2.7",
"league/flysystem": "1.0.44",
"league/oauth2-client": "2.2.1",
"mikehaertl/php-shellcommand": "1.2.5",
"paragonie/random_compat": "v2.0.12",
"pixelandtonic/imagine": "v0.7.1.3",
"psr/http-message": "1.0.1",
"psr/log": "1.0.2",
"seld/cli-prompt": "1.0.3",
"seld/jsonlint": "1.7.1",
"seld/phar-utils": "1.0.1",
"swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "v6.0.2",
"symfony/console": "v3.3.6",
"symfony/debug": "v3.3.6",
"symfony/filesystem": "v3.3.6",
"symfony/finder": "v3.3.6",
"symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "v1.8.0",
"symfony/process": "v3.3.6",
"yiisoft/yii2": "2.0.15.1",
"yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "2.0.8",
"yiisoft/yii2-composer": "2.0.6",
"yiisoft/yii2-debug": "2.0.13",
"yiisoft/yii2-queue": "2.0.2",
"yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "2.1.1",
"zendframework/zend-escaper": "2.6.0",
"zendframework/zend-feed": "2.8.0",
"zendframework/zend-stdlib": "3.2.0",
"solspace/craft3-freeform": "2.4.0",
"dolphiq/redirect": "1.0.18"
 },
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
  "modules\\": "modules/"
}
},
"config": {
"optimize-autoloader": true,
"platform": {
  "php": "7.0"
}
},
"scripts": {
"post-root-package-install": [
  "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
],
"post-create-project-cmd": [
  "@composer dump-autoload -o",
  "@php craft setup/welcome"
]
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share your project's composer.json file?

Comment: That doesn't looks like a Craft composer.json file... it should be the one at the root of your Craft project's folder.

Comment: Apologies - updated the question

Answer (score 1):

How about changing the yii2-queue version number in composer.json and then running a composer update?

Answer (score 0):

Change your composer.json's "require" section to this:

```
"require": {
    "craftcms/cms": "^3.0.23.1",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^v2.4.0",
    "craftcms/ckeditor": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "craftcms/redactor": "^2.1.6",
    "solspace/craft3-freeform": "^2.4.0",
   "dolphiq/redirect": "^1.0.18"
},
```

If you have Composer installed from the command line (https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx), then you can run `composer update` from your project's root, let it complete, load the Craft Control Panel and you should be set.

If you don't have Composer installed from the command line, then running an update from Craft's Control Panel should basically achieve the same thing.

Comment: Doing this resulted in a server error 500 unfortunately.

Comment: What's the underlying error message?  If Craft generated it, it'll be in `storage/runtime/logs`. If your web server did, it'll be in your web server's error logs.

Comment: The server error was:

Comment: Warning: require(.../vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .../public_html/index.php on line 20

Comment: Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '.../vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear') in .../public_html/index.php on line 20

Comment: Basically vendor/craftcms/cms failed to upload. So I uploaded a backup of the directory to get the installation running again.